# GradientColor over an ImageView

Tags: android

I have an ImageView that I want to put a gradient Color over it.

So,I use FrameLayout that I put an ImageView and a View inside it.

```
   <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/bg_login" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_login_gradient"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And here is my gradient Color that I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient
android:angle="135"
android:endColor="#ff6272DA"
android:startColor="#0026d0ce" />
</shape>
```

The problem is this:
I want this result :
[image: Target]

But,I get this:
[image: Bug]

Please Help ;)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you verify that the image isn't this blurry without the gradient? Maybe it's picking compressed version of the resource

Comment: Yeah I'm sure that the image itselef is not blurry

Comment: I would suggest you to put your background image in drawable instead of mipmap.

Comment: Putting  background image in drawable is not working because of 
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(216000000bytes) bitmap.
this problem

Comment: That means the image is too large. Could you scale the image to more reasonable resolutions? The mipmap is for launcher icons only

Comment: Then try putting it in drawable-xxhdpi

Comment: Thanks it worked very well

Comment: Cheers pal, Good luck!

Comment: As per the official documentation, `mipmap` is to be used for the app icon **only**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting background image in drawable-xxhdpi is worked for me.

Comment: Then (please) accept your own answer, so to remove it from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Comment: Sorry,
The error when clicking on accept sign: "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"